# Time series analysis help

Tags: time-series, r

I have a time-series analysis regression project in R.

I am instructed that the regression should use pre-post events as a dummy variable to examine certain events' effect. I am also told that the time-series analysis should be centered around these events. where the event will have the value of “0”, the day before will be “-1”, and the day after “+1”.

I am not too sure if I follow the instruction and would like to ask what does this mean. does it mean 2 days before will be -2, 3 days before -3 etc? how would pre-post event act as a predictor?